# Error message logged when appending view for global loading state

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm trying to have a default loading view. Following the information here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_legacy-code-loadingroute-code

```
LoadingView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'global-loading',
  elementId: 'global-loading'
});

ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    loading: function() {
      var view = this.container.lookup('view:loading').append();
      this.router.one('didTransition', view, 'destroy');
    }
  }
});
```

The view appears to be rendering but I get an error message logged to the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null
```

It looks like it specifically has to do with callind ".append()"
Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: It looks like this error was being triggered when the Chrome Ember Inspector was running. After I disabled the extension I didn't see the error message again. I think it was trying to get _debugContainerKey on an object that perhaps didn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Marking this as answered.

It looks like this error was being triggered when the Chrome Ember Inspector was running. After I disabled the extension I didn't see the error message again. I think it was trying to get _debugContainerKey on an object that perhaps didn't have it.